# How to completely remove jitsi* package?

Tags: debian

I'm using Debian 8 Jessie OS. I've corrupted installation of jitsi package. I need to uninstall jitsi from my PC. I can't do it. That's my output from terminal:

```
root@debian:~# apt-get purge --remove jitsi*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'jitsi-meet-prosody' for regex 'jitsi*'
Note, selecting 'jitsi-meet' for regex 'jitsi*'
Note, selecting 'jitsi-meet-tokens' for regex 'jitsi*'
Note, selecting 'jitsi-videobridge' for regex 'jitsi*'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jicofo : PreDepends: jitsi-videobridge but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@debian:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lua-event lua-expat lua-filesystem lua-sec lua-socket lua5.1 prosody
Suggested packages:
  lua-zlib lua-dbi-postgresql lua-dbi-mysql lua-dbi-sqlite3
Recommended packages:
  lua5.1-sec lua5.1-event
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  jitsi-meet-tokens
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lua-event lua-expat lua-filesystem lua-sec lua-socket lua5.1 prosody
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 1 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/417 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,175 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 174595 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing jitsi-meet-tokens (1.0.1073-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-tokens (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-tokens
======  How can you help?  (doc: https://wiki.debian.org/how-can-i-help ) ======

-----  Show old opportunities as well as new ones: how-can-i-help --old  -----
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@debian:~# apt-get purge jigasi jitsi-meet jicofo jitsi-videobridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jigasi
root@debian:~# apt-get purge jitsi-meet jicofo jitsi-videobridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jitsi-meet-prosody : Depends: prosody but it is not going to be installed or
                               prosody-trunk but it is not installable
                      Depends: jitsi-videobridge but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: jicofo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@debian:~# apt-get purge jitsi-meet jicofo jitsi-videobridge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
^[[AYou might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jitsi-meet-prosody : Depends: prosody but it is not going to be installed or
                               prosody-trunk but it is not installable
                      Depends: jitsi-videobridge but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: jicofo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I can't remove this package. Can I access to this package from directory tree and remove it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Start with `dpkg --configure -a` to flush out any remnants from that failure.

After that, explicitly add the `jitsi-meet-prosody` package to the invocation of `apt-get purge`, so that it knows that your intent is indeed to remove that, too - otherwise it tries to maintain the existing state.

In fact, judging by your intent you might want to just purge `'jitsi.*'` so you don't chase each new subpackage. (NB: `apt-get` uses regular expressions, `dpkg` uses globs.)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing has worked... do the following:
Back up your status file:

```
$ sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status_bk
```

Check that if your backup file exists

```
$ ls /var/lib/dpkg/
```

You can also open the backup status file

```
$ less /var/lib/dpkg/status_bk
```

Open the current status file using `xed` (`xed` is the default text editor for Linux Mint 18, but you can use others like `gedit` or vi if you have that available in your system):

```
$ sudo xed /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find the package you want to remove.
For example: `jitsi-meet-tokens`

Delete or Remove all the entry text about the target package.
In this case(target package is jitsi-meet-tokens), delete this following section of text in the status file.

```
Package: jitsi-meet-tokens
Status: deinstall ok half-installed
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 53
Maintainer: Jitsi Team <dev@jitsi.org>
Architecture: all
Source: jitsi-meet
Version: 1.0.1073-1
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, prosody-trunk (>= 1nightly607), libssl-dev, luarocks, jitsi-meet-prosody
Description: Prosody token authentication plugin for Jitsi Meet
Homepage: https://jitsi.org/meet
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save, and now let's check if the package error has been resolved.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Enjoy!
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=233205